# [Uncertainty]: The value of $\frac {xy} {x^2 +y^2}$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis

I have a doubt about the value of this function:

> $$f(x,y)= \frac {xy} {x^2 +y^2}$$ 
>   at the point $(0,0)$.

My teacher wants me to prove that function allows partial derivatives (DONE) and that's not continuous at $(0,0)$ (DONE, only if I'm sure that $f(0,0)=0$).

Comment: In the question, this condition is not added. Is it possible to find that the value is (0,0)?

Comment: @Yagger "in order for it to be well defined" Right. "and continuous" Sorry? How would this make $f$ continuous at $(0,0)$?

Comment: No, the formula does not provide a value at $(0,0)$.

Comment: @Did you're right, I thought the limit at $(0,0)$ was 0.

Comment: So the question lacks this condition, right?

Comment: @volkov no, you can't talk about continuity in a point where a function is not defined

Comment: @volkov  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, this function is not defined at $(0,0)$. It is usually convenient to **define** $f$ to equal that equation everywhere except at $(0,0)$ and then to define it to be $0$ at $(0,0)$. The function you’ve described and the function I’ve described are slightly, but importantly, different.

If your function isn’t defined at $(0,0)$ then the question “is this function continuous at $(0,0)$” is ill-posed, just like asking if $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ would be.

If your function is redefined to be $0$ at $(0,0)$, then you can show it is discontinuous by taking two different paths to $(0,0)$ and showing that they have different limiting values.

Comment: So, I can define f in $(0,0)$ equal to $0$ ; right?

Comment: @volkov yes, you can. You can actually define it to be anything you wish, though from a certain POV $0$ is the most natural option.

Comment: And from another POV $\frac 25$ is the most natural option.

Comment: And from still another POV, 1/3 is the most natural option.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(x,y)$ is not defined at $(0,0)$ it is meaningless consider the continuity at that point.

Note that we can also define $f(0,0)=0$ but the function remains not continuous at the origin indeed

- $x=0\implies f(0,y)=0$
- $x=y=t\to 0\implies \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{t^2}{2t^2}=\frac12$

Comment: I used polar coordinates: $x= R cos (t)$ and $y= R sin(t)$

Comment: Yes it’s ok also with polar coordinates of course!

Comment: And the limit does not exist!

Comment: Exactly, therefore f(x,y) is not continuous at the origin. Recall that this is valid defining a fixed value for f(x,y) at the origin.